# Errors - PHP Basic File Upload

Tags: php, file, file-upload, upload

HTML Code

```
<html>
<title>File</title>
<body>

<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload_3.php" method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="300000">
  Invia questo file: <input name="userfile" type="file"></br>
  <input type="submit" value="Invia File">
</form>

</body>

</html>
```

PHP Code:

```
?php
if (!isset($_FILES['userfile']) || !is_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'])) {
  echo 'Non hai inviato nessun file...';
  exit;    
}


if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], "/var/www/html" . $_FILES['userfile']['name'])) {

echo "Ce l'hai fatta!";
}
else{
echo "Riprova bro";
}

?>
```

I don't understand the reason I always obtain the error "Riprova bro".

**With function "move_uploaded_file" I should move the file from the temporary location into /var/www/html, but it doesn't work.**

[Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cop90.png)

This is my configuration inside php.ini file:
[PHP.ini configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5CY1.png)

Thanks.

Comment: `"/var/www/html"` is probably missing a trailing slash, e.g. `"/var/www/html/"`

Comment: You need a final `/` in `"/var/www/html"`. Also, check the permissions.

Comment: What is the exact error message that you get?

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Have you checked the target destination of the uploaded file? What about permissions?

Comment: See my updated answer, I hope will fix your issue.

Comment: please copy/paste code instead of linking pictures

Comment: Did you solve your issue?

Answer (score -2):

Your code is OK. You cannot upload the file due to 3 reasons:

1) When the `limit` (`MAX_FILE_SIZE`) is reached you cannot upload any file, `300000` equal about to `300 KB`, try to increase your `limit`.

You have:

```
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="300000">
```

Try with:

```
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="3000000">
```

Where `3000000` is about `3 MB`

2) You are assuming that your path exists, check first if exists and if not create your full path recursively and setting in the while the permission (`0755`):

```
if (!is_dir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/var/www/html/")) { 
  @mkdir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/var/www/html/", 0755, true);
}
```

3) You are currently assuming that the `path` is correct, false, the path `"/var/www/html"` is not, try the [$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) and the slash (`/`) at the end of your path. See this change:

```
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/var/www/html/" . $_FILES['userfile']['name'])) {
```

With these 3 adjustments your script works perfectly. Now it prints: `Ce l'hai fatta!`

Finally I suggest you to fix:

`?php` with `<?php`

I hope this helps.

Comment: Please don't offer "copy this"-answers. Rather explain what went wrong in the original code and how that could be fixed

Comment: Sorry, but I don't have a clue how anybody should be able to find a connection between the original error message and your code. It does work completely different